# perforce: avoid forced sync after normal "get latest revision" did not get all

Tags: perforce

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell perforce only to sync *the missing* (from given workspace view) files, not overwriting correctly existing, i.e. a way to avoid the use of `p4 sync -f` after a normal "get latest revision" (`p4 sync`) did not get all.

Comment: I did not set the file status to writeable outside Perforce---so only when checking out.

Comment: [closed] from my side, see 3rd answer.

As a side note: `p4 diff -sd ./...` can be used to avoid checking whole workspace but current directory only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
p4 diff -sd | p4 -x- sync -f
```

This is a chained command that will find all known files in your workspace that are not #head revision (`p4 diff -sd`) then force sync on **only those files** (`p4 -x- sync -f`). Note the use of the `-x-` which instructs the second command to read from standard input (STDIN).

Comment: Very cool, **this is what I looked for**!
It ensures I have all, while saving potentially a lot of time vs. `p4 sync -f` only (plus showing how to check for 'gaps' in the local workspace) - Thanks!

Comment: +1. This is the same answer that I would have written. I edited the your answer, adding more detail about how that command/s work.

Answer (score 1):

If `p4 sync` doesn't get the file, then the perforce server thinks you already have it.

`p4 sync <missing file>#0` to make the server sync to the missing file, then `p4 sync <missing file>` to get a new copy.

Alternatively, `p4 sync -f <missing tree>/...` will sync just the missing tree.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of avoiding the global `-f` option.

If the normal sync didn't get the latest version of the file then Perforce thinks that you already have it. Have you been setting the file status to writeable outside Perforce?

If you know which files/folders are affected you could use `-f` on just those files/folder which will be quicker, but does mean you might miss something.